# Magento 2.4.3-p3 security scan failed XS Vulnerability (APPSEC-1539)

Tags: magento2, magento2.4.3

Our Magento 2.4.3-p3 site failed the XS Vulnerability check. Does anyone know how this can be fixed?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The XS Vulnerability (also known as Cross-Site Scripting Vulnerability) in Magento 2.4.3-p3 can be fixed by following these steps:

1. Update Magento to the latest version - Magento released security patches for this vulnerability in its latest version. It's recommended to upgrade your site to the latest version of Magento 2.4.x, which has the security patch for XS Vulnerability.
2. Install the security patch - Magento also released a security patch (SUPEE-116459) for older versions of Magento 2.4.x, which includes the fix for XS Vulnerability. You can download the patch from the Magento security center and apply it to your site.
3. Disable HTML tags - You can also disable the use of HTML tags in user-generated content such as product reviews, comments, and contact forms. This will prevent attackers from injecting malicious scripts into your site.
4. Use Content Security Policy (CSP) - Implementing CSP headers in your site's HTTP response can help prevent XSS attacks by restricting the sources from which your site can load scripts, stylesheets, and other resources.

It's important to note that fixing XS Vulnerability is crucial for maintaining the security of your Magento site. You should take action as soon as possible to prevent any potential security breaches.

Comment: Mm.. I can't find that patch... Where can I find the security patch SUPEE-116459? Do you have a link related to that patch? My installed version is: Magento Open Source 2.4.3-p3